# Norm of $(A+B)^{-1}(A-B)$?

Tags: matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

For $a, b$ two positive constants, we know that
\begin{align*}
\frac{a-b}{a+b}
\end{align*}
belongs to the interval (-1, 1).

My question is the following: is there a similar statement for matrices? More precisely,

> Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be two **positive definite symmetric** matrices (not necessarily commuting). Is the norm of the matrix
>   \begin{align*}
> M=(A+B)^{-1}(A-B)
> \end{align*}
>   strictly less than $1$ (**eventually** by **adding assumptions** on $A$ and $B$)?

I tried the following. We can also write this matrix as
\begin{align*}
M= (I_n + A^{-1}B)^{-1}(I_n - A^{-1}B).
\end{align*}
We can also write $A^{-1}B = A^{-1/2} (A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2}) A^{1/2}$. Moreover, since $A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2}$ is symmetric and positive definite, it may be written as
\begin{align*}
A^{-1/2} B A^{-1/2} = U^\intercal D U
\end{align*}
for $U$ unitary and $D$ diagonal positive definite. Injecting these two expressions in the formula for $M$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
M = A^{-1/2} U^\intercal (I+D)^{-1}(I-D) U A^{1/2}.
\end{align*}
Then, the norm of $U^\intercal (I+D)^{-1}(I-D) U$ is strictly less than $1$ (because $(I+D)^{-1}(I-D)$ is a diagonal matrix with diagonal entries of the form $(1-d)/(1+d)$ with $d>0$ and $U$ is unitary).

But when is this also true for the norm of $M$? Is there another way to proceed?

Comment: Since $M$ has its spectrum in $(-1,1)$ (as you have shown), we can see that the similar matrix
$$
(A+B)^{-1/2}(A-B)(A+B)^{-1/2}
$$
have norm less than $1$.  I suspect that your $M$ will "usually" fail to have norm less than $1$, though.

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you. I was wondering if this could be true for $M$ if $A$ is diagonal for example. But it looks like unless $A$ and $B$ commute, this is not true in general.

Comment: If the statement held for all diagonal $A$ (and positive definite $B$), we would be able to conclude that it holds for all choices of positive definite $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Indeed, thank you.